# Error while subclassing NSFileWrapper in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsfilewrapper

I have subclassed `NSFileWrapper` to specialise it for my own file wrapper while retaining the file handling functionality that `NSFileWrapper` offers.

I have not overriden anything and not implemented any of the `NSFileWrapper`'s initialisers in my subclass. Instead I have provided my own initialiser as appropriate for my file wrapper.

Inside the initialiser, I have used

```
super.init(URL: url, options: options, error: outError)
```

and attempted to do `documentation = self.fileWrappers["Documentation"] as NSFileWrapper` where `documentation` is a `NSFileWrapper` property in my subclass. But execution stops at this step saying

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(URL:options:error:)' for class 'MyClass'
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Is NSFileWrapper not meant to be subclassed? Why is it looking for the initialiser in the subclass in the first place?

EDIT: My initialiser is

```
init(playgroundURL url: NSURL!, options: NSFileWrapperReadingOptions, error outError: NSErrorPointer)
```

and I am passing `nil` to `options` and `outError` while calling it.

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare options & outError? I don't think the issue is subclassing...

Comment: I have updated my question. In any case, XCode is complaining only in the next line when I do ```documentation = self.fileWrappers["Documentation"] as NSFileWrapper```. Doesn't this means the first phase of initialisation was successful?

Comment: And based on the new rules for initialisers, shouldn't it be impossible for a designated initialiser to look for another designated initialiser in the same class(based on the whole 'funnel' concept and stuff)